# HTTPS thought shadowsocks --mptcp

Tags: https, socks, mptcp

I would like to ask if it is possible to forward HTTPS through the following diagram

A USER -> Wi-Fi -> SQUID -> SHADOWSOCKS_CLIENT -> MPTCP -> SHADOWSOCKS_SERVER -> INTERNET

HTTP is working.

We have already ask for here for advice how to use shadowsocks properly for https (https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/issues/926)

However there might be other solutions.

I would like to ask for an advice.

thank you